# ● Test suite failed to run Jest encountered an unexpected token export { BsModalRef }

Tags: angular, jestjs

Not able to run test cases when using js library like BS-MODAL.
Details:

```
/home/test-app/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/modal/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export { BsModalRef } from './bs-modal-ref.service';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the **ngx-bootstrap** to **transformIgnorePatterns** Working fine.

```
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!ngx-bootstrap)"
    ]
```

if you got one more error after adding the ngx-bootstrap

```
Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)
```

1. Install

> `jest-canvas-mock`

2. Add config in `jest config:setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts', 'jest-canvas-mock']`

at final in your angular **package.json** file **jest** link this

```
 "jest": {
 .........,
..........
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!ngx-bootstrap)"
    ],
............,
............
  }
```

Reference link https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock/issues/2#issuecomment-500307391

I followed the same steps and working for me.